# AzCopy "segmentation fault" error after copying file with bash script

Tags: bash, azcopy

**I'm installing an AzCopy utility (to copy files from Azure Storage) to my local VM but can't run it due to "Segmentation fault" error.**

To install AzCopy I'm using a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp/

# this just removes previous azcopy downloads if for some reason there are some
rm *azcopy* &> /dev/null

echo "Downloading azcopy..."
echo 
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
wget https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux && echo -n "Download complete, unpacking...  " || (echo "Error downloading the file - aborting"; exit 1)
checkstr=$(tar --exclude=*.txt -tf downloadazcopy-v10-linux | grep /azcopy)

if [[ $checkstr == *"/azcopy" ]];
then echo "azcopy file found - verication OK"
else (
  echo "ERROR - azcopy file missing - aborting"
  exit 1
)
fi

tar --strip-components=1 --exclude=*.txt -xzvf downloadazcopy-v10-linux & > /dev/null && echo "Unpacking OK" || (echo "Unpacking failed - aborting"; exit 1)

echo "Copying azcopy to /usr/local/bin ... "
sudo cp /tmp/azcopy /usr/local/bin/ && echo "Copying successful" || (echo "Error copying file - aborting"; exit 1)

echo "Making it executable ..."
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/azcopy && echo "Azcopy installed OK !" || (echo "Can't make the binary executable - aborting"; exit 1)

# cleaning up :)
rm -rf *azcopy* & > /dev/null
```

Installation is seemingly successful but when I try to run 'azcopy' command I always get "Segmentation fault" regardless of whether I run it with or without parameters - for example:

```
root@bbackup:/opt/githubbackup# azcopy
Segmentation fault
root@bbackup:/opt/githubbackup# azcopy login --identity
Segmentation fault
root@bbackup:/opt/githubbackup# azcopy asdfgh
Segmentation fault
root@bbackup:/opt/githubbackup#
```

**When (after the script has done it's job) I go to '/tmp/' and run the file with './azcopy' I get normal output and the utility works as expected**. But when run it from '/usr/local/bin' there's "segmentation fault" error.

When I copy the file with 'cp /tmp/azcopy /usr/local/bin' file also works as supposed to.

Everything points to the fact of using the script.

P.S. - I have lot's of free disk space available.

I tried using different working directory ('/aztmp/') with no effect and tried changing files owner & group with 'chown root:root azcopy' to no avail too.

I could extract the file directly to the '/usr/local/bin' but since this is a production system I want an extra layer of security.

My suspicion is that file gets corrupted while copying from '/tmp/' but why ?

Comment: As an aside, the parentheses arund the `else` are completely unnecessary, and waste a process.

Comment: You are running `azcopy` without a full path; are you sure it's running the one from `/usr/local/bin`? What's the output of `type -all azcopy`?

Comment: I did run `which azcopy` to make sure I'm running proper executable, it returned the same path as `type -all azcopy` which was of course `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Just asking for the safe side: You were running `type -all azcopy` in the same shell where you got the segfault? And do I understand it correctly, that running `/usr/local/bin/azcopy` runs fine, while just doing `azcopy` gives a segfault?

Comment: I was getting an error regardless whether I used full path or not - the only difference was - when azcopy was installed using script it didn't work - when copied manually on the other hand - everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution found.**

The issue was this part:

```
tar --strip-components=1 --exclude=*.txt -xzvf downloadazcopy-v10-linux & > /dev/null && echo "Unpacking OK" || (echo "Unpacking failed - aborting"; exit 1)
```

Note the `& >` part which instead of redirecting all output to `/dev/null` told the tar to run in the background (`&` sign) and then output everything from there to `/dev/null`.

After removing the space all is working :)

**P.S. This is just something that my colleague at work found out but since he doesn't have SO account I'm posting this.**